# Using both publishOn and subscribeOn on a flux results in nothing happening

Tags: spring, kotlin, project-reactor

Whenever i use both subscribeOn and publishOn nothing is printed.
   If I use only one it will print.
   If I use subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()) or elastic it works.
   Any ideea why that is?

It was my understanding that publishOn affects on what thread it gets published and subscribe on on what thread the subscriber runs. Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
fun test() {
        val testPublisher = EmitterProcessor.create<String>().connect()
        testPublisher
                .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .map { it ->
                    println("map on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    it
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())  
                .subscribe { println("subscribe on ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
        testPublisher.onNext("a")
        testPublisher.onNext("b")
        testPublisher.onNext("c")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println("---")
    }
```

Comment: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/project-reactor-publishon-vs-subscribeon-difference

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`subscribeOn` rather influence where the *subscription* occurs. That is, the initial event that triggers the source to emit elements. The `Subscriber` 's `onNext` hook on the other hand is influenced by the closest `publishOn` up in the chain (much like your `map`).

But `EmitterProcessor`, like most `Processor`s, is more advanced and can do some work stealing. I'm unsure why you don't get anything printed in your case (your sample converted to Java works on my machine), but I bet it has something to do with that Processor.

This code would better demonstrate `subscribeOn` vs `publishOn`:

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c") //this is where subscription triggers data production
        //this is influenced by subscribeOn
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("before publishOn: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
        //the rest is influenced by publishOn
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("after publishOn: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .subscribe(v -> System.out.println("received " + v + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

This prints out:

```
before publishOn: parallel-1
before publishOn: parallel-1
before publishOn: parallel-1
after publishOn: elastic-2
received a on elastic-2
after publishOn: elastic-2
received b on elastic-2
after publishOn: elastic-2
received c on elastic-2
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this aspect for me!

Comment: But I'm having a hard time realizing why we need two? publishOn and subscribeOn. Where all we are trying to achieve is to run the blocking/time taking task of the chain in a separate thread pool.

Comment: you wouldn't necessarily need the two for that case, subscribeOn should suffice to change the initial thread

Comment: `publishOn` is typically used for fast publisher, slow consumer(s) scenarios.

`subscribeOn` is typically used for slow publisher, fast consumer(s) scenarios.

as explain by @SimonBaslé here, for `subscribeOn` the event is published and received on same thread where as in case of `publishOn` it is different.