# publishOn vs subscribeOn in Project Reactor 3

Tags: reactive-programming, publish-subscribe, project-reactor, publisher, reactive-streams

I am using publishOn vs subscribeOn both on the same flux as follows:

```
    System.out.println("*********Calling Concurrency************");
    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
      .map(i -> i * 2)
      .log()
      .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
      .subscribe(elements::add);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
```

Although, when i use both, nothing is printed in logs.
But when i use only publishOn, i got the following info logs:

```
*********Calling Concurrency************
[info] | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
[info] | request(256)
[info] | onNext(1)
[info] | onNext(2)
[info] | onNext(3)
[info] | onNext(4)
[info] | onComplete()
-------------------------------------
```

Is that publishOn is more recommended than subscribeOn? Or it has more preference than subscribeOn? What is the difference between the two and when to use which?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41939335/438319 has a good response to a very similar question

Comment: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/project-reactor-publishon-vs-subscribeon-difference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a small documentation which i got:

> publishOn applies in the same way as any other operator, in the middle of the subscriber chain. It takes signals from downstream and replays them upstream while executing the callback on a worker from the associated Scheduler. Consequently, it affects where the subsequent operators will execute (until another publishOn is chained in).
>
> subscribeOn applies to the subscription process, when that backward chain is constructed. As a consequence, no matter where you place the subscribeOn in the chain, it always affects the context of the source emission. However, this does not affect the behavior of subsequent calls to publishOn. They still switch the execution context for the part of the chain after them.

and

> publishOn forces the next operator (and possibly subsequent operators after the next one) to run on a different thread. Similarly, subscribeOn forces the previous operator (and possibly operators prior to the previous one) to run on a different thread.

Comment: to be precise "publishOn" it should be from upstream to downstream and not the opposite

Answer (score 44):

It took me sometime to understand it, maybe because `publishOn` is usually explained before `subscribeOn`, here's a hopefully more simple layman explanation.

`subscribeOn` means running the initial source emission e.g `subscribe(), onSubscribe() and request()` on a specified scheduler worker (other thread), and also the same for any subsequent operations like for example `onNext/onError/onComplete, map etc` and no matter the position of subscribeOn(), this behavior would happen

And if you didn't do any `publishOn` in the fluent calls then that's it, everything would run on such thread.

But as soon as you call `publishOn()` let's say in the middle, then any subsequent operator call will be run on the supplied scheduler worker to such `publishOn()`.

here's an example

```java
Consumer<Integer> consumer = s -> System.out.println(s + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

Flux.range(1, 5)
        .doOnNext(consumer)
        .map(i -> {
          System.out.println("Inside map the thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          return i * 10;
        })
        .publishOn(Schedulers.newElastic("First_PublishOn()_thread"))
        .doOnNext(consumer)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.newElastic("Second_PublishOn()_thread"))
        .doOnNext(consumer)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newElastic("subscribeOn_thread"))
        .subscribe();
```

The result would be

```
1 : subscribeOn_thread-4
Inside map the thread is subscribeOn_thread-4
2 : subscribeOn_thread-4
Inside map the thread is subscribeOn_thread-4
10 : First_PublishOn()_thread-6
3 : subscribeOn_thread-4
Inside map the thread is subscribeOn_thread-4
20 : First_PublishOn()_thread-6
4 : subscribeOn_thread-4
10 : Second_PublishOn()_thread-5
30 : First_PublishOn()_thread-6
20 : Second_PublishOn()_thread-5
Inside map the thread is subscribeOn_thread-4
30 : Second_PublishOn()_thread-5
5 : subscribeOn_thread-4
40 : First_PublishOn()_thread-6
Inside map the thread is subscribeOn_thread-4
40 : Second_PublishOn()_thread-5
50 : First_PublishOn()_thread-6
50 : Second_PublishOn()_thread-5
```

As you can see the first `doOnNext()` and the following `map()` is running on the thread called `subscribeOn_thread` , that happens till any `publishOn()` called, then any subsequent call would run on the supplied scheduler to that `publishOn()` and again this will happen for any subsequent call till anyone calls another `publishOn()`.

Comment: The code you have in there is a painful brain teaser if one forgets the fact that map executes once per cyle and not ahead of time, the fact that "Inside map" is printed with the same thread name is an awesome explanation of how subscribeOn changes the thread of the emission and how publishOn changes the thread of execution based on the position of the chain rather than the instant of its calling. Very nice

Comment: What if the `subscribeOn()` is undefined, does it by default run in the original thread?

Answer (score 3):

`publishOn` is applied in the middle of a chain. It affects subsequent operators after `publishOn` - they will be executed on a thread picked from publishOn's scheduler.

```
 Flux.range(1, 2)
      .map(i -> {
          System.out.println(String.format("First map - (%s), Thread: %s", i, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
          return i;
      })
      .publishOn(schedulerA)
      .map(i -> {
          System.out.println(String.format("Second map - (%s), Thread: %s", i, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
          return i;
      })
      .blockLast();
```

The output is

```
  First map - (1), Thread: main
  First map - (2), Thread: main
  Second map - (1), Thread: scheduler-a-1
  Second map - (2), Thread: scheduler-a-1
```

If you place a `subscribeOn` in a chain, it affects the source emission in the entire chain

```
Flux.range(1, 2)
      .map(i -> {
          System.out.println(String.format("First map - (%s), Thread: %s", i, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
          return i;
      })
      .subscribeOn(schedulerA)
      .map(i -> {
          System.out.println(String.format("Second map - (%s), Thread: %s", i, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
          return i;
      })
      .blockLast();
```

The output is

```
  First map - (1), Thread: scheduler-a-1
  Second map - (1), Thread: scheduler-a-1
  First map - (2), Thread: scheduler-a-1
  Second map - (2), Thread: scheduler-a-1
```

reference article can be found [here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/project-reactor-publishon-vs-subscribeon-difference)

Answer (score 2):

Following is an excerpt from excellent blog post https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers

#### publishOn

This is the basic operator you need when you want to hop threads. Incoming signals from its source are published on the given Scheduler, effectively switching threads to one of that scheduler’s workers.

This is valid for the `onNext`, `onComplete` and `onError` signals. That is, signals that flow from an upstream source to a downstream subscriber.

So in essence, every processing step that appears below this operator will execute on the new Scheduler s, until another operator switches again (eg. another `publishOn`).

```
Flux.fromIterable(firstListOfUrls) //contains A, B and C
    .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .map(url -> blockingWebClient.get(url))
    .subscribe(body -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " from first list, got " + body));

Flux.fromIterable(secondListOfUrls) //contains D and E
    .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .map(url -> blockingWebClient.get(url))
    .subscribe(body -> System.out.prinln(Thread.currentThread().getName + " from second list, got " + body));
```

**Output**

```
boundedElastic-1 from first list, got A
boundedElastic-2 from second list, got D
boundedElastic-1 from first list, got B
boundedElastic-2 from second list, got E
boundedElastic-1 from first list, got C
```

#### subscribeOn

This operator changes where the subscribe method is executed. And since the subscribe signal flows upward, it directly influences where the source Flux subscribes and starts generating data.

As a consequence, it can seem to act on the parts of the reactive chain of operators upward and downward (as long as there is no `publishOn` thrown in the mix):

```
final Flux<String> fetchUrls(List<String> urls) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(urls)
           .map(url -> blockingWebClient.get(url));
}

// sample code:
fetchUrls(A, B, C)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
  .subscribe(body -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " from first list, got " + body));

fetchUrls(D, E)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
  .subscribe(body -> System.out.prinln(Thread.currentThread().getName + " from second list, got " + body));
```

**Output**

```
boundedElastic-1 from first list, got A
boundedElastic-2 from second list, got D
boundedElastic-1 from first list, got B
boundedElastic-2 from second list, got E
boundedElastic-1 from first list, got C
```